# ActionScript 3.0 - Dispatch event class to class

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, dispatchevent

I'm working in Action Script 3.0 and I have a question in DispatchEvent class.

following code is standalone class.

I want to dispatch event to 'main' class and 'sub' class when event occured.

I'm stuck on this issue. please help me.

```
package com
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.sub;

    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        public static const BTN_CLICKED:String = "btn_Clicked";

        public function main():void
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        public function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            var flashVars:Object = {};

            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            if(parent != null && parent.parent != null)
            {
                flashVars = parent. parent.loaderInfo.parameters;
            }
            else
            {
                flashVars = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters;
            }
            //entry point
            var subClass:sub = new sub;
            subClass.init();

            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
            addEventListener(BTN_CLICKED, onbtnClicked, false, 0, true);
        }

        public function onClick(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(BTN_CLICKED));
        }

        public function onbtnClicked(e:Event)
        {
            trace("clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

and below is 'sub' class.

```
package com
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.main;

    public class sub extends MovieClip
    {
        public function sub():void
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }

        public function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            //entry point
            trace("sub class loaded");
        }
    }

}
```

yes, there's nothing in 'sub' class... how can I get dispatch event in sub class?

Comment: I think that your code works for 'main' class, but what you mean by 'sub' class ?

Comment: I don't see where is the `sub` class. You need a link to that object to dispatch events.

Comment: sorry, I put some 'sub' class too.